# Oracle plsql trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

How do I only allow a user to insert a row into a relational table only once a day?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON Table_name
declare date[type?]
count int := 0;
BEGIN
if(00:00 to sysdate)
END IF
END
```

Comment: You can add a `date` column to the table and then add a trigger, so that `:NEW.date := trunc(sysdate, 'DD');` and add a unique constraint on that column.

Comment: look up `DBMS_SCHEDULER`.

Comment: `date` is a reserved keyword and cannot be a column name unless quoted such as `"Date"` @Radagast81 . Also `count` is a reserved keyword that cannot be a local variable name within a PLSQL code block.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Just wanted to give a short idea of how this can be done in pseudocode and not a complete answer. I thought it would be clearer if stated that way ignoring minor problems that are straight forward to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Why use a trigger when you can use a constraint?

```
create table t (
  c1       int,
  ins_date date default sysdate,
  ins_day  date as ( trunc ( ins_date ) ),
  constraint one_per_day unique ( ins_day )
);

insert into t ( c1 )
  values ( 1 );

insert into t ( c1 )
  values ( 2 );

ORA-00001: unique constraint (CHRIS.ONE_PER_DAY) violated

select * from t;

C1    INS_DATE              INS_DAY                
    1 07-NOV-2019 09:31:14  07-NOV-2019 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisSaxon has the correct idea of creating a constraint instead of trying a trigger. Not only is it cleaner it'll work, whereas a trigger **will NOT work** (cleanly anyway). Any trigger attempting to enforce this would of necessity need to select from the same table resulting in a mutating table exception (ora-04091) or would need to be a :( compound  trigger :(. But we can take Chris' suggestion a step further. Make the column ins_day a virtual column. Also as you indicated "allow a *user* to insert a row into a relational table only once a day" implies you can have multiple entries per day, just not by the same user. Incorporating these then we arrive at:

```
create table test_1per_user_day (
  t1pd_id  integer,
  user_id  integer,
  ins_date date default sysdate,
  vir_1per_day  date GENERATED ALWAYS AS (trunc(ins_date)), 
  constraint t1d_one_per_day unique (user_id, vir_1per_day )
);

-- test run individually and stlect * from test_1per_day after each 
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
insert into test_1day(t1pd_id, user_id) values (1,1);
insert into test_1day(t1pd_id, user_id, ins_date) values (1,1, sysdate-2);
insert into test_1day(t1pd_id, user_id, ins_date,vir_1per_day) values (1,1, sysdate-1,sysdate);
insert into test_1day(t1pd_id, user_id) values (2,2);
insert into test_1day(t1pd_id, user_id) values (2,2);
update test_1day set vir_1per_day = sysdate;
```